# Safari Mobile doesnt open up camera on http

Tags: safari

I am creating a JavaScript web app that uses the devices camera to scan qr codes but it is all thru my website. The qr code scanner uses the built in webcam on my macbook when i am developing on localhost. When I open the local app on safari on iphone, it doesnt even ask for device permission to allow access to the camera.

I feel like this is a device permission issue more than an actual coding question but I could be wrong :/ The url I open on safari is 192.168.0.12:3000. I have a feeling there is a permissions setting that blocks access to the camera when not an https request

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I stumbled on it trying to find out the same thing and later found the answer in below linked SO question.

There is an option to allow media capture from insecure site in dev tools. WebRTC -> Allow media capture on insecure sites. See link for mor details.

[getusermedia-is-not-allowed-in-localhost-safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44523609/getusermedia-is-not-allowed-in-localhost-safari-11)

Comment: That answer isn't relevant to Safari Mobile, though.